# Xsd2Code auto properties not working?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xsd, xsd2code

I'm using Xsd2Code to generate a C# serializer/deserializer class for my XSD file. Also I have enabled the generation of auto properties.

Problem #1:
Xsd2Code still generates private fields in addition to the auto properties. This should not be necessary.

Problem #2:
Only the private fields get initialized. The auto properties are not initialized and stay null.

Comment: Yes, this seems to be the case. There is even a bug report from 2014 https://xsd2code.codeplex.com/workitem/17167, so it seems Xsd2Code is abandoned.

Comment: All these points have since been corrected. In any case, the community edition version of xsd2code ++ handles that well.